# Basic Powershell question on getting piped values in result

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

New to Powershell coding here.

Given this means of looking up USB drive letter assignments:

```
$Foo2 = Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{Get-WMIObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{Get-WMIObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}
```

How would I go about getting each deviceID of the first two sections of code, namely:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"}
```

in the final result? So instead of the current result being just drive letters, the output would include the lookup value alongside the result, for example:

```
deviceID             driveLetter
-------------------  -----------
 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  D:
 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  F:
 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  G:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from just running `get-volume | ? drivetype -eq removable`, [-pipelinevariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.4#-pipelinevariable) or -pv to the rescue, with a custom "disk" variable.  It's a bit confusing that the drive letter is originally called a "deviceid" property.

```
Get-Ciminstance win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} -pv disk |
%{Get-Ciminstance -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.
  DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE 
  AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
%{Get-Ciminstance -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.
  DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
select @{n='deviceid';e={$disk.deviceid}},@{n='driverletter';e={$_.deviceid}}

deviceid           driveletter
--------           -----------
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 E:
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3 F:
```

Comment: Be ready for the future. WMI is deprecated. Use CIM.

Comment: @lit, good point, but to be precise: it isn't _WMI_ that is deprecated, but the WMI _cmdlets_ - the CIM cmdlets still use WMI on Windows.

Comment: @mklement0, that appears to be the underlying reality, but that may not be of much significance to someone trying to get code to run using PowerShell Core.

Comment: @lit, the distinction is important to avoid conceptual confusion. You don't want people thinking that WMI _as such_ is to be avoided, outside the context of PowerShell.